# Angular: ngSubmit not sending form

Tags: angular, formgroups, ng-submit

Everything is working fine but when I click the submit button (ngSubmit) is not working.
FormsModule + ReactiveFormsModule are already imported and the submit button is inside the form. Do you have any ideas?

This is the html, ng-template #editMode will be called

```
<table>
    <tr class="tr_header">
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Weight in [kg]</th>
        <th>Reps</th>
        <th>Pause in [s]</th>
        <th>Options</th>
    </tr>
    <tr *ngFor="let data of readData">
        <div *ngIf="isEdited == data.MPID;then editMode else showMode"></div>
        <form [formGroup]="musclepartForm" (ngSubmit)="musclepartUpdateSubmit()">

            <ng-template #editMode>
                <td>
                    <input class="edit_td" formControlName="musclepart" type="text" placeholder="{{data.name}}">
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input class="edit_td" formControlName="weight" type="text" placeholder="{{data.weight}}">
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input class="edit_td" formControlName="reps" type="text" placeholder="{{data.reps}}">
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input class="edit_td" formControlName="pause" type="text" placeholder="{{data.pause}}">
                </td>
                <td class="td_options">
                    <div>
                        <button type="submit" mat-icon-button color="primary" aria-label="Accept">
                            <mat-icon>check</mat-icon>
                        </button>
                        <button (click)="isEdited=false" mat-icon-button color="warn" aria-label="Cancel">
                            <mat-icon>cancel</mat-icon>
                        </button>
                    </div>
                </td>
            </ng-template>
        </form>

        <ng-template #showMode>
            <td class="td_name" (click)="gotoExercize(data.MPID, data.name)">{{data.name}}</td>
            <td>{{data.weight}}</td>
            <td>{{data.reps}}</td>
            <td>{{data.pause}}</td>
            <td class="td_options">
                <div>
                    <button (click)="editMusclepart(data.MPID)" mat-icon-button color="primary" aria-label="Edit muscle grouü">
                        <mat-icon>edit</mat-icon>
                    </button>  
                    <button (click)="deleteMusclepart(data.MPID, data.name)" mat-icon-button color="warn" aria-label="Add muscle part">
                        <mat-icon >delete</mat-icon>
                    </button>
                </div>
            </td>
        </ng-template>

    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Can you move `<form>` tag within `<ng-template>` and let me know if that fixes this?

Comment: @AakashGoplani I already tried that but then my entire form (inputs+buttons) completely disappears. Therefore I put my form outside <ng-template>.

Comment: @user16405471 Is this the entire form? If not, could you share the whole thing? From the looks of it, nothing should display at all since all the form HTML is nested inside of an `<ng-template>` and it isn't being called anywhere.

Comment: HI @PaulThorsen  I added the whole table for better understanding.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There seems to be a conceptual misunderstanding in your form. [Reactive forms use a model-driven approach](https://angular.io/guide/reactive-forms#reactive-forms). This means that there should be an underlying model of all the displayed data that is editable. As all the rows in your table are editable, your form should represent this. In essence, your entire table should be one big form and the edit and submit buttons should basically toggle the visibility of the form rows, while saving the data to your form. You can use your `readData` to create a form to handle all the interactions in your table.

I created [this stack blitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-prmq44?file=src/app/app.component.html) to help show what that might look like. The code isn't perfect, but hopefully you can adapt it to your needs.

Comment: thank you very much for your effort my friend. That helped me a lot. You were right: I had to put the entire table into the form.